# How to add on mysql query if message already deleted by the user?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have my messages table, I would like to know if how I can add messages is_deleted by the user here is my table:

```
id fromid toid message is_read deleted_to deleted_from  date
1  1      2    test1   1       0          0             2012-09-06 00:00:10
2  2      1    test2   1       0          0             2012-09-06 00:00:11
3  1      3    test3   1       0          0             2012-09-06 00:00:12
4  3      1    test4   1       0          0             2012-09-06 00:00:13
5  2      1    test5   1       0          0             2012-09-06 00:00:14


Users
MemberID    username
1           user1
2           user2
3           user3
```

What should I do to be able not so select the deleted message ? Is my table right or I need to add table and have a condition in my query ?

For example: the user sends me a message and I have deleted the message and now the message will not be visible on my side. But the on the sender side He can see his message, if he's not yet deleted the message. Its like facebook messaging. You can delete the full conversation or you can just delete selected messages.

I just created my mysql query:

```
SELECT 
                IF(derived_messages.toid = '$user', derived_messages.fromid, 
                derived_messages.toid) friend1,c.UserName,
                derived_messages.message, derived_messages.fromid, derived_messages.toid,
                derived_messages.is_read,
                derived_messages.date
                FROM 
                (SELECT * 
                FROM messages
                ORDER BY date desc) derived_messages
                INNER JOIN Users c ON c.MemberID = IF(derived_messages.toid = '$user', derived_messages.fromid, 
                derived_messages.toid)
                WHERE (derived_messages.toid='$user' OR derived_messages.fromid='$user') 
                GROUP BY friend1 ASC 
                ORDER BY derived_messages.date DESC, derived_messages.id DESC
```

**Now, I would like to know where I am going to add the condition for the message  deleted.**

Thank you.!

Comment: how do you know if the message is deleted?

Comment: For example: the user sends me a message and I have deleted the message and now the message will not be visible on my side. But the on the sender side He can see his message, if he's not yet deleted the message. Its like facebook messaging. You can delete the full conversation or you can just delete selected messages.

Answer (score 1):

Add column is_deleted. Set it to 0 when false. 1 when true. 0 by default.

```
SELECT message, etc FROM messages WHERE is_deleted = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Wayne, but If I am going to set as 1 when its deleted both user and receiver will not see the message, even if only one users has been deleted the message

Comment: Then you should change the query based on who is reading it. If the sender is checking his/her inbox, use delete_to and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

It could simply be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE is_deleted = 0
```

Comment: Thanks  but If I am going to set as 1 when its deleted both user and receiver will not see the message, even if only one users has been deleted the message

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to understand what code is currently using the existing `deleted_to` and `deleted_from` fields. If you just add a new column `is_deleted`, you have to ask yourself, are you comfortable that all code that reads this table will know to look at this new field?

Judging by you existing schema, I would say that a *message* can be considered *deleted* by setting a date for the `deleted_from` field, and then undeleted by setting the `deleted_to` field. The potential hole in this logic, is what happens if the message is deleted a second time? You lose the knowledge of when the message was deleted the first time. Maybe this is ok for your purposes.

I agree that adding a new field `is_deleted` is acceptable so long as the existing fields `deleted_to` and `deleted_from` are kept in a consistent state.

You don't want some of your code using this logic

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE is_deleted = 0
```

and other code using logic something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE 
    @query_date < deleted_from
    OR @query_date > deleted_to
```

You may end up with inconsitencies in determining when a message is considered to be *deleted*. This is especially problematic if more than one application is reading your database table.

**Edit** from your comments

OK, to keep things simple here's what I suggest...

1. Let's ignore the fields `deleted_to` and `deleted_from` for determining when a message is deleted. I'm not sure how to intend to use these fields
2. Rename field `date` to be named `date_created` for clarity
3. Add a `datetime` field named `date_updated`
4. Add a `bit` field named `is_deleted` defaulting to "zero" (i.e. 0 = false, 1 = true)

In your code, when deleting a message set the is_deleted field to 1 (true). The date_updated field shoud be set everytime you edit or delete a record. You can determine when a record is deleted by checking "is_deleted = 1" and referring to the "date_updated" field.

You query only records that have not been deleted, add `WHERE messages.is_deleted = 0` as shown below

```
SELECT 
     IF(derived_messages.toid = '$user', derived_messages.fromid, 
     derived_messages.toid) friend1,c.UserName,
     derived_messages.message, derived_messages.fromid, derived_messages.toid,
     derived_messages.is_read,
     derived_messages.date
FROM (
    SELECT * 
     FROM messages 
     WHERE messages.is_deleted = 0
     ORDER BY date desc
     ) derived_messages
INNER JOIN Users c 
        ON c.MemberID = IF(derived_messages.toid = '$user', derived_messages.fromid, derived_messages.toid)  
WHERE 
    (derived_messages.toid='$user' OR derived_messages.fromid='$user')
GROUP BY 
    friend1 ASC 
ORDER BY 
    derived_messages.date DESC, derived_messages.id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Brad, I have my mysql query, I would like to know what part I am going add the condition for deleted messages.

Comment: What is the Data Type of the fields deleted_to and deleted_from? You have shown a "zero" value in your question but these would logically be `datetime` fields wouldn't they?

Comment: in my fields deleted_to and deleted_from I just created that fields, normaly I am thingking to put the user ho deleted the message.

Comment: I have added my sql statement above , I would like to know where or what else I am going to add. Thank you.